# Java code doesn't work

Tags: java

Hey guys i am have a problem in java coding. I am using eclipse and my code is as following:

```
public class Application {
  public static void main(String[] args){
    int loop = 100;
    int looop = 90;
    while(loop > looop)
      System.out.println(looop);
    looop = looop + 1;
  }
}
```

The output should be like this:

```
90 
91
92
93
94
95
96
97
98
99
```

But it keeps on printing 90 and doesn't stop the loop.

Comment: Use proper brackets to define your desired scope.

Comment: *Always* put braces around your loop and conditional blocks. The Java language doesn't require them, but it helps you to see the extent of the block more easily. I've reindented your code - is the problem clear now?

Comment: I figured out that there is a bracket error but i am not sure where to put these brackets?

Comment: Also try using better naming. It is a common beginner mistake and it makes it even harder for the beginner to understand code, even his own. Variable names like "loop" and "looop" is pretty bad for readability.

Comment: @Vlasec I was just having fun with codes i know its pretty bad but i couldn't think of anything else :(

Answer (score 2):

only a bracket problem:

```
int loop = 100;
    int looop = 90;
    while(loop > looop) { //bracket begings
        System.out.println(looop);
        looop = looop + 1;
    }//bracket ends
```

Comment: It worked i was just not familiar with the bracket thing. Thumbs up for you!

Comment: @TaahaRauf glad to help